# Trying to write an alternative Hello World using Scala and Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have little previous experience with deprecated Scala actor, recently I started to learn Akka actor, they seem to be quite different.

I completed this tutorial http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/hello-world.html

Next, I am trying to write an alternative Hello World, using a paradigm similar to deprecated Scala actor. But I have some difficulties (see in-line comments):

```
class Echo extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case a: Any => println(a)
    case "end" => context.stop(self)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val echo = new Echo()

    // Where is explicit Actor.start() ?

    // "! is not a member", but Akka's official Hello World used ! to send message
    echo ! "Hello"
    echo ! "end"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code.

1) You cannot create an actor by simply instantiating its class. You need to obtain an ActorRef using actorOf. To do this you need to start up an ActorSystem that will manage the creation of Actors.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
  val echo = system.actorOf(Props[Echo], "myactor2")
  echo ! "Hello"
  echo ! "end"
}
```

2) Your receive method is wrong too. An pattern of type `Any` will match everything including `"end"`. Try something like this:

```
   override def receive = {
    case "end" => context.stop(self)
    case a:String => println(a)
  }
```

Here a message is printed only if it is not `"end"` in which case it does not match the first case and falls of to the second one.